# Assign own View Classes to Storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, storyboard

See this storyboard containing a Navigation View, Gestures, and a few Views.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gwuy3.png]

Also within is a `TabView`, which contains an `UIImageView` and `UITableViewController`.

To apply my data to this TableView, I need to assign a Controller by using `msExampleTableViewController`.

The problem: the input/dropdown field removes entry after pressing Enter (like if this class is not assignable).

What is wrong here, and how can it best be done?

Answer (score 0):

NA UITableViewController does assume that the root view will be a UITableView. When you combines UITableView with others controllers.. you can do in your Controller (ViewController in your case):

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet UITableView* tableView;
```

In Interface Builder set both the delegate and dataSource outlets of the table view to be equal to its superview's view controller (File's Owner)...

Now, Your view controller implementation should be the typical TableViewController implementation: `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, etc.